# Change function input submit to id

Tags: javascript

I'm looking at some code here that targets the dom by the type="submit" and I'm trying to change it to be the id="go" of a input or button in the dom.  How can I rewrite this to still work.

```
    t.addEventListener("submit", function (A) {
    A.preventDefault();
    var C = w();
    var B = new C;
    B.append(q.value || q.placeholder);
    saveAs(B.getBlob("text/plain;charset=" + s.characterSet), (h.value || h.placeholder) + ".html")
    }, false);
```

Comment: So you are trying to submit data using the ID as an identifier rather than the Name?  Just trying to gain some clarity

Comment: Magic variables A,B,C,t,q,h,w!

Comment: Well the problem is there is multiple forms and this submit button is inside another form which does something else.  I'm just trying to get it to function by calling the input another way.

Comment: @Blynn: The `submit` event is associated to the form element being submitted. If you're trying to access the form's submit button, assign an identical `name` for all submit buttons so that you can access it relatively via form's property and generalize your function. e.g.: `A.target.theSubmitButton`.